# ValidationGroup is undefined when defined in code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to set the ValidationGroup name in my code behind. I have a nested grid and if I set the ValidationGroup name in the markup then when I click the 'Add' button to validate the entries, it checks the first nested grid and if that is valid it succeeds, else it fails.
So in my RowDataBound event I set the values of the ValidationGroups for each nested grid, shown below:

```
protected void UserGroupGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    int tiGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(UserGroupGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
              //      m_strUserID = CommonMethods.ParseUserID(User.Identity.Name);

                    GridView tgvGroupMember = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GroupMemberGridView");
                    populateGroupMemberGrid(tgvGroupMember, tiGroupID);

                    //Get the Footer controls that have the new entry data
                    Control tFooterControls = CommonMethods.getFooterControls(tgvGroupMember);                
                    DropDownList tddlRecipientNames = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName") as DropDownList;
                    m_strXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetAllPossibleGroupMembers(m_strUserID, tiGroupID);
                    DataTable tdtAllGroupMembers = CommonMethods.ParseXML(m_strXmlTableData);
                    tddlRecipientNames.DataSource = tdtAllGroupMembers;
                    tddlRecipientNames.DataTextField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberName"].ToString();
                    tddlRecipientNames.DataValueField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberID"].ToString();
                    tddlRecipientNames.DataBind();
                    tddlRecipientNames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));//This is needed for the jquery-chosen dropdown to add data-holder text
                    tddlRecipientNames.ValidationGroup = "DDLVal_" + tiGroupID.ToString();

                    Button tbtnAdd = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvAddButton") as Button;
                    tbtnAdd.ValidationGroup = "DDLVal_" + tiGroupID.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TO DO: Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
            }
        }
```

However, when I check all of the Page_Validators in the jquery function, both are 'undefined'. This is the jquery function:

```
function Validate(sender) {
 for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                alert(Page_Validators[i].validationGroup);
            }
}
```

Where can I set my ValidationGroup names in the code behind so that I can have them on my client side.
For completeness, this is the nested grid markup:

```
<div id="div<%# Eval("GroupID") %>" style="display:none">
<asp:GridView ID="GroupMemberGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="GroupMemberGridView_RowDeleting" 
     OnRowCommand="GroupMemberGridView_RowCommand" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MemberID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Member Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>               
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="mggvDDLMemberName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                   class="chosen-single" data-placeholder="Choose member…">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqValueDDLMemberInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                       ControlToValidate="mggvDDLMemberName" 
                        ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active Device(s)">                   
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="mggvLblActiveDevice" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("ActiveDevice").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>                   
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="mggvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Group Member?')" >
                </asp:Button>
            </ItemTemplate>                                     
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="mggvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Member" Width="90%" ClientIDMode="Static"
                    CssClass="gridActionbutton" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="return Validate(this);" >
                </asp:Button>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```